# MATLAB: Can axes tick labels be accesed as text objects?

Tags: matlab, properties, plot

I'm curious is it possible to change text properties of tick labels independently of axes properties. Do they have handles? I'd like to control their position better, alignment, color, fonts, etc.
I know I can substitute them with text labels, but it has some drawbacks. Any alternative solutions?

Particularly, is it possible to put xticklabels between ticks, that are irregular?

```
plot(1:100)
set(gca,'xtick',[30 45 53 70 95])
grid on
```

I need to put xticklabels in the middle between grids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put xicklabels between ticks, I would plot a second set of axes on top of the first. [LINKZOOM](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21414) from the file exchange makes sure that you have no problems zooming.

```
plot(1:100),
ah=gca;
%# make arbitrary ticks
set(ah,'xtick',[30 45 53 70 95],'xticklabels',[])

%# create new axes with labels placed in the middle
ah2=axes('parent',gcf,'position',get(ah,'Position'),'color','none',...
'ticklength',[0,0],'xtick',([45 53 70 95]+[30 45 53 70])/2,'xlim',[0,100],'ylim',[0,100])

%# link all axes in the figure
linkzoom;
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about it. Not working yet tough. Cannot see new labels for some reason. I'll continue tomorrow.

Comment: @yuk: I had the same problems with not seeing the labens in the beginning. I guess I plotted about 10 times before I figured it out :)

Comment: I have added xlim explicitly now

Comment: So, I assume, the answer for the subject question is no, right?

Comment: As far as I know, the answer is no for the subject question.